# Shared preferences and app uninstallation

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

What happen when an app that use `SharedPreferences` object for store information is `uninstalled`?

System will remove automatically related preferences, or they still remain into device?

Answer (score 4):

`SharedPreferences` are deleted when you uninstall your app.
If you want to restore your `SharedPreferences` when your app is **reinstalled** then you should add a `BackupAgentHelper` to your app. Together with the `SharedPreferenceBackupHelper`, it backups the `SharedPreferences` to the cloud (if the device supports it). When the app is reinstalled the data is restored.

See:

[BackupAgentHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/backup/BackupAgentHelper.html)

[SharedPreferenceHelper (contains all the code you need to implement it)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/backup/SharedPreferencesBackupHelper.html)

[general Backup guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you specify the `-k` option during uninstallation via adb (`adb uninstall -k my.package.name`) the shared preferences will be deleted like everything that can be found in `/data/data/my.package.name/`.

From the adb documentation:

> ('-k' means keep the data and cache directories)

You should use the `-k` option with caution, since the UID on the system is bound to your application's signature. So changing the signature will make the re-installation of your app on the device fail.

Answer (score 1):

SharedPreferences and all of the app data (excluding data on external storage) will be deleted

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences, databases, caches and private files are removed.
Yo should have read this

[Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)